# How can I use taggit-selectize so that all user-made tags show up in the autocomplete?

Tags: django, django-taggit

I found this project https://github.com/chhantyal/taggit-selectize and it seems to do what I want, but the example app is incomplete, so I don't know how to use it. What I basically want is that users will be able to write their own tags for a post, and that if they are typing one that has been used before by someone else, it will show up in autocomplete. I also want a search function that will use the autocomplete in the same manner. I'm sure it's not very complicated but the readme only explains how to install and what some things mean, and I was looking for a very minimal working example that makes the autocomplete work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have a very specific use case. I hope my example does not over-complicate things (I add extra fields to my Taggit model). Please be aware you *may* need to load css and js in your html, as per this [issue](https://github.com/chhantyal/taggit-selectize/issues/16). I am using [Django Crispy Forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

In my app settings:

```
    TAGGIT_TAGS_FROM_STRING = "taggit_selectize.utils.parse_tags"
    TAGGIT_STRING_FROM_TAGS = "taggit_selectize.utils.join_tags"
    TAGGIT_SELECTIZE_THROUGH = "jobsboard.models.SkillTags"
    TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE = True

    TAGGIT_SELECTIZE = {
        "MINIMUM_QUERY_LENGTH": 2,
        "RECOMMENDATION_LIMIT": 10,
        "CSS_FILENAMES": ("taggit_selectize/css/selectize.django.css",),
        "JS_FILENAMES": ("taggit_selectize/js/selectize.js",),
        "DIACRITICS": True,
        "CREATE": False,
        "PERSIST": True,
        "OPEN_ON_FOCUS": True,
        "HIDE_SELECTED": True,
        "CLOSE_AFTER_SELECT": False,
        "LOAD_THROTTLE": 300,
        "PRELOAD": False,
        "ADD_PRECEDENCE": False,
        "SELECT_ON_TAB": False,
        "REMOVE_BUTTON": True,
        "RESTORE_ON_BACKSPACE": False,
        "DRAG_DROP": False,
        "DELIMITER": ",",
    }
```

In my jobsboard/models.py:

```
from taggit.models import TagBase, GenericTaggedItemBase
from taggit_selectize.managers import TaggableManager

class SkillTags(TagBase):
    LANGUAGE = "la"
    STATISTICS = "st"
    CODING = "co"
    DISCIPLINE = "di"

    TYPES = (
        (LANGUAGE, "language"),
        (STATISTICS, "statistics"),
        (CODING, "coding"),
        (DISCIPLINE, "discipline"),
    )
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPES, default=DISCIPLINE, max_length=2)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)


class TaggedModel(GenericTaggedItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(SkillTags, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_items")


class Job(TimeStampedModel):

    tags = TaggableManager(_("skillset required"), blank=True, through=TaggedModel)
```

In my urls:

```
url(r'^hirer/new/$', NewJobView.as_view(), name='hirer_new_job')
```

In my jobsboard/views.py:

```
class NewJobView(FormView):
    template_name = 'jobsboard/new_edit_job.html'
    form_class = NewAndEditJobForm
```

In my jobsboard/forms.py:

```
class NewAndEditJobForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('tags',)
```

For my jobsboard/templates/jobsboard/new_edit_job.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
  {{ block.super }}
   {% crispy form %}  
{% endblock content %}
```

for my templates/base.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  {% block css %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Your stuff: Third-party CSS libraries go here -->

  {% endblock %}

  {% block extrahead %}

  {% endblock %}  
</head>
<body>

{% block content %} 
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascript %}

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

{% endblock javascript %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize any tags I write at all.
Do you know why?
I pasted all the code here http://paste.debian.net/1034781/

I wasn't sure what the TAGGIT_SELECTIZE_THROUGH = "jobsboard.models.SkillTags" made. Did I change it accordingy?

Comment: Have you any js errors via the browser console? V tricky to debug remotely! Does your project currently consist of this feature only? A long shot! If so, pehraps it makes sense I get your project working and we provide it as example project for django taggit selectize.

Comment: The only error is that at `(jQuery || django.jQuery);` it says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at`... The project has other features, but they're not directly in contact with this one.

Comment: That's the error. You need to get jquery loaded as early as possible. Relates to the last Comment here (re using pure js to detect scripts have loaded, not jquery) https://github.com/chhantyal/taggit-selectize/issues/16

Comment: I see. I have added the "include jquery" script to the base_generic, and I have added 

`{% block javascript %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/taggit_selectize/js/selectize.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block css %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <link href="/static/taggit_selectize/css/selectize.django.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}`

To the template of submit. But where do I put this code from the last comment? In the template? If yes, where in the template? Where I'm loading the other libraries?

Comment: You may want to restrict taggit-selectize js and css to the one page where you use it. I added a base.html demo to my answer -- I'd try loading your jquery in your <head></head> section. I'm going to request a push to django-taggit-selectize to remove that jquery 'detect when scripts loaded' feature with a pure js alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176541/discussion-between-andyw-and-sandor-des).

Comment: Note that the only property needed to make this work is ```TAGGIT_SELECTIZE_THROUGH```

Answer (score 0):

I shall try and give an example as lean as possible:

app/models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from taggit_selectize.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

app/views.py:

```py
from app.models import Post
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class PostEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['name', 'tags' ]
    success_url = '/'
```

app/templates/app/post_form.html:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Speichern">
</form>

{% endblock %}

{% block css %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <link href="{% static "taggit_selectize/css/selectize.django.css" %}" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
  {{ block.super }}
    <script src="{% static "taggit_selectize/js/selectize.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and a templates/base.html:

```html
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- IMPORTANT: get jquery loaded ASAP. if you load it too late you get JS errors from the taggit-selectize. -->

    {% block css %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Important Note**: I was having the same problems up until the point where I moved the `jquery`-loading up into the header.